# Getting rid of html attributes and its values while parsing using jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am trying to parse multiple html documents in such a way that I get only the tags discarding all its attributes and values. Can someone help me please.

For example: `<img src="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Italian Trulli">`

changes to

`<img>`

Similarly, I want this to work for all the tags in an HTML document.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the attributes of a single element you can use this:

```
element.attributes().asList()
        .stream().map(Attribute::getKey)
        .forEach(element::removeAttr);
```

To remove the attributes of all elements you can use this in combination with `document.getAllElements()`:

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse("<img src=\"pic_trulli.jpg\" alt=\"Italian Trulli\">");
document.getAllElements()
        .forEach(e -> e.attributes().asList()
                .stream().map(Attribute::getKey)
                .forEach(e::removeAttr));
```

The result will be this:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <img>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all elements from document and then over each element's attributes which should allow you to remove them.

Demo:

```
String html = "<img src=\"pic_trulli.jpg\" alt=\"Italian Trulli\">" +
        "<div class=\"foo\"><a href=\"pic_trulli.jpg\" alt=\"Italian Trulli\" non-standard></div>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

System.out.println(doc);
for (Element el : doc.getAllElements()){
    for (Attribute atr : el.attributes().asList()){
        el.removeAttr(atr.getKey());
    }
}
System.out.println("-----");
System.out.println(doc);
```

Output:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <img src="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Italian Trulli">
  <div class="foo">
   <a href="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Italian Trulli" non-standard></a>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
-----
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <img>
  <div>
   <a></a>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to receive a clear document structure, you need to remove text and data nodes as well. Consider the following snippet.

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com").get();
document.getAllElements().forEach(element -> {
      element.attributes().asList().forEach(attr -> element.removeAttr(attr.getKey()));
      element.textNodes().forEach(Node::remove);
      element.dataNodes().forEach(Node::remove);
    });
System.out.println(document);
```

Output:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <meta>
  <meta>
  <meta>
  <style></style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
   <h1></h1>
   <p></p>
   <p><a></a></p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```